# 'psql' command keeps giving error in terminal

Tags: java, database, postgresql, authentication

I'm trying to local in instantly when I type `psql` command inside my root path in my terminal but I'm having problem like this. I asked for help, and they told me if I make new user, I won't have same problem with it but it keeps popping up, even thought I checked all privileges for new user. I also read on stackoverflow about changing some file in postgresql but that also didn't work. So if you know any way that could help me instantly to log in to my user when I type `psql` in my terminal I would appreciate it.

````
PS C:\Users\Ante> psql
Password for user Ante:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Ante"```
````

Comment: Why the `java` tag?